# Index out of range when tying field to a bean (string issue?)

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a field in a repeat control that is tied to a bean:

```
<xp:inputText
    value="#{requestBean.driverChanges[rowIndex]}"
    id="DriverChange">
</xp:inputText>
```

getDriverChanges() is the following:

```
public Vector<String> getDriverChanges() {
    return driverChanges;
}
```

and is set with the following:

```
setDriverChanges(doc.getItemValue("DriverChanges", Vector.class));
```

When the DriverChanges field has a value in it, my code works fine. However, if DriverChanges is empty/blank I get the following:

```
Error getting index 0
Array index out of range: 0
```

I've tried computing the value in the xp:inputText field with code that always returns a vector, but this causes my xp:inputText to become read-only (I can't edit/change the value and save it).

Anyone have any ideas on how I can make a string return as a vector via a bean and still keep the xp:inputText editable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed getDriverChanges() in my Java bean to the following:

```
public Vector<String> getDriverChanges() {
    if (this.driverChanges.isEmpty()) {
        Vector<String> emptyVector = new Vector<String>(1);
        emptyVector.add("");
        this.driverChanges = emptyVector;
        return driverChanges;
    } else {
        return driverChanges;
   }
}
```

I'm forcing an empty vector to be created. I think the issue was that my vector was somehow being converted into a string when the field was empty.

Comment: that's a known issue, that getItemValue returns String instead of Vector if field contains just single value. there are some snippets to workaround it. you did one yourself. https://coderwall.com/p/cpdxpw/domino-ssjs-return-vector-helper-function

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize Vector driverChanges for all rowIndexes available in repeat.
The number of entries in Vector driverChanges has to be at least the same as the number of repeat's value entries.

Your error message  `Array index out of range: 0` tells you that your Vector driverChanges exists but has no entries.